# Image Array "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to do some operation in numpy array. Actually I'm trying to zoom an image using the nearest neighbour rule. I have facing that above titled issue.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray

img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')

rows = img.shape[0]*2
cols = img.shape[1]*2

zoomed = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=img.dtype)

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        zoomed[i][j] = img[int(i/2)][int(j/2)]

cv2.imshow('Input Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Zoomed Image', zoomed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: `print(img.shape)`. It should have 3 dimensions, so `img[int(i/2)][int(j/2)]` is an array, while `zoomed[i][j]` should be a scalar.

Comment: Show the full error message

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
zoomed = np.zeros((rows, cols, 3), dtype=img.dtype)
```

The error you're getting is happening because `img[int(i/2)][int(j/2)]` is actually three RGB values and `zoomed[i][j]` can only hold integers. Creating `zoomed` to have shape `(rows, cols, 3)` allows `zoomed` to hold 3 integers at every row, column location.